# Indexing a dictionary from file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for a simple store that will load products and prices from a file and load it to dictionary and then be able to use it into the program.. but i am trying not to hard code any of the code values so if the file changes it because un-usable.

my file = test.txt contains

```
banana:3
apple:4
```

Here what i tried so far

```
d = {}
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    name,score = line.split(":")
    d[name] = int(score)

print('''
Welcome to my store
What would you like to buy today

[1] banana
[2] apple
[3] orange

''')

menumain = int(input('Enter product number to continue: '))
if menumain == 1:
    value = int(input('how many banana you will buy'))
    new = d[name][0] * value
    print('You ordered',value,'banana(s), Which will cost you',new )
else:
    print('error! wrong menu')
```

what i need is

```
 new = d[name][0] * value
```

is it modify this line so it auto picks the index.. what user selected and from the product name. it use the product's value

in this case index 0 will try to get the value banana which is 3 but it is not working

Im doing this because if i write d['banana'] it will work but if something from the outer file is changed the code will break. So i need something so it works soft-coded

Comment: What is `[0]` for in `d[name][0]`?

Comment: Have you tried `print(d)` to see what's actually in `d` after you finish loading it? I think it's not what you're expecting it to be, and that's what's causing your confusion (even though I'm not sure what you're expecting it to be).

Comment: Actually trying it for indexing 0 for first index. but obviously it doesnot work

Comment: You should rename `value` -> `quantity` and `new` -> `price`. Also, your dict has product names and not numbers as keys.

Comment: Also, what is `name` supposed to be in `d[name][0]`? It looks like it's just whatever was left over from the `for name in …` loop above, which isn't very useful.

Comment: abarnert d is the dictionary what i want is to get the first item of the dictionary without entring its name in this case its banana..

Comment: I didn't ask what `d` is, I asked what `name` is. But I think your answer makes the confusion clear anyway. Dictionaries don't _have_ a first item. Their items don't have any inherent order, and can only be looked up by name. If you want to access things in order, by index rather than by name, you want a list, not a dict. (If you really need to access things both by index and by name, you can use something like `OrderedDict`, but that's more complicated, and usually not what you need.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't actually want a dict here at all. You're trying to access "the first item". That implies that you want a list:

```
lst = {}
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    name,score = line.split(":")
    lst.append([name, int(score)])
```

Now we have a list of pairs, we can get the first one:

```
lst[0]
```

… or, if you've asked the user to give you a number:

```
lst[choice]
```

Of course that's a `[name, score]` pair, not just a score. So if you want to get the score, you need another `[]`:

```
new = lst[choice][1] * value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list that maps from numbers to product names. You can do:

```
product_names = d.keys()
print('''
Welcome to my store
What would you like to buy today

''')
for i, p in enumerate(product_names):
    print ("%d) %s" % (i+1, p))
choice = int(input("Enter product number: "))
if i <= len(product_names):
    name = product_names[i+1]
    value = int(input("How many %s do you want to buy: " % name))
    new = d[name] * value
    print("You ordered %d %s(s), which will cost you %d" % (value, name, new))
else:
    print("That's not a valid product number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this? (Using dict here is not very efficient here)

```
d = []
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    name,score = line.split(":")
    d.append([name,int(score)])

d = sorted(d)

print('''
Welcome to my store
What would you like to buy today

''')

i = 0
for prod in d:
      print("["+str(i+1)+"] "+prod[0])
      i += 1

print("\n")

menumain = int(input('Enter product number to continue: '))
if menumain <= (len(d)-1) and menumain >= 0 :
    prod = d[menumain-1]
    value = int(input('how many '+prod[0]+'(s) you will buy? '))
    print('You ordered '+str(value)+' '+prod[0]+'(s), Which will cost you '+ str(prod[1]*int(value)) )
else:
    print('error! wrong menu')
```